# Serilog not creating log file when running on Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm having problems to enable logging when running **ASP.NET Core** application on **Linux**. I'm using **Serilog.Sinks.File** (but also tried with **RollingFile**) with following configuration defined in appsettings:

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": { "path": "core_log.log", "rollingInterval": "Day" }
  }
],
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
"Properties": {
  "Application": "CORE service"
}  }
```

I also tried with with RollingFile sink using **pathFormat** but without success. What ever I try, application is not creating the log file.

I also tried multiple variants of path like: /var/test/app/core_log.log or just simply core_log.log but I'm not seeing file anywhere. I tried searching it using:

```
sudo find / -name '*.log' -print | grep core_log
```

It is important to mention that when running the same app on the Windows, everything works well and I can see log file created.

Did somebody have similar problem with Serilog on Linux? Can it be something related with privileges?

Comment: Do you have any exception when you log information ?

Comment: Nope, nothing..

Comment: Almost certain to be filesystem permissions - try creating the file first, giving the user that the web app is running under permission to write it, and then specifying the full path in the config; HTH!

Comment: You can also take a look at the [SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog), it probably describe your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just fixed this same problem with this configuration:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo
                .File(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "logs/.log"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Pay special attention to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. This will point to your Linux deploy folder. I guess it's possible to read the folder from a config file too.

I also had to create the folder manually, as pointed out by Nicholas (thank you!, not only for this), but not the file.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution but works. I would prefer to know how to write my logs in /var/logs folder.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer on this page didn't solve it for me. I'm running .net 6 with Serilog 2.12.0. The Serilog configuration is loaded from appsettings.json.

The problem was that Serilog couldn't create or write to the application's log folder under /var/log.

What solved the problem was:

```
mkdir /var/log/myapp/
chown www-data:www-data /var/log/myapp/
chmod 755 /var/log/myapp
```

This is the core of my configuration:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console"
            },
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "/var/log/myapp/log-.log",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] | {MemoryUsage} bytes | <{ClientIp}> <{ClientAgent}> {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }      
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issues.  I can hard code my serilog settings in the program.cs file and everything works as expected.  Reading the appsettings.json serilog configuration throws no errors and fails to configure the serilog sinks.

**working:**

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LoggerLevel.Switch)
    .Enrich.WithThreadId()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    .Enrich.WithProcessId()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:9091", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
    .CreateLogger();
```

**Not working:**

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LoggerLevel.Switch)
    .CreateLogger();

"Serilog": {
"Using": [],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Verbose",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Verbose",
    "System": "Verbose"
  }
},
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console"
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
      "path": "logs/application_event_log.json",
      "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": {
      "serverUrl": "http://localhost:9091"
    }
  }
]
```

}

Both solutions work fine on windows.

Updated with Resolution: adding using statements to the serilog section in app settings.Json

```
 "Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Seq" ],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Verbose",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Verbose",
    "System": "Verbose"
  }
},
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
"WriteTo": [
  { "Name": "Console" },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
      "path": "logs/application_event_log.json",
      "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": {
      "serverUrl": "http://10.0.0.111:9091"
    }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: Adding using statements to the app settings file resolved my serology issues on Linux